# Plaid Link popup browser leaves my capacitor app and the flow is interrupted

Tags: android, angular, capacitor, inappbrowser, plaid

I have an app made with capacitor and angular, I have implemented Plaid Link and it work correctly in browser but when running it in the android app the popup browser opens in the device browser and after finishing the mock form it doesn't go back to the application, I think by continue the form in the device browser the context is lost from the application, has anyone implemented Plaid Link succesfully in a capacitor app? and prevent this behaviour somehow, like continue the form in an inapp browser?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not redirecting properly. Are you adding the android_package_name during token creation? And have deep links working in your android app?

Comment: We are using plaid with a payment processor as intermediary so we can't handle the redirect and for business rules reason we  disallow the deep links, but the issue was put on hold to be retaken in the future, thanks for answering friend. cheers